# How will I implement this function with decoder and multiplexer?

Tags: digital-logic

```
Inputs     Output 
A    B      F
0    0      C.D
0    1      C
1    0      C+D
1    1      C XOR D
```

According to the logic input-output relations

a-) Find the simple form of the F logic function.
b-) Implement the F logic function with the decoder.
c-) Implement the F logic function with the multiplexer.

Hello, I found examples on the implementation of the boolean function given on the internet. But I could not interpret this table. What are the C and D outputs, how will I find them and then I will simplify them.

I think it's easy to implement once you find a simple function.

Comment: C and D are additional *inputs* to your system, while the A and B inputs select which function of C and D to present on the single output F.

Comment: So for example, when A and B are zero, will I use C and D gates? So how is the A 0 B 1 situation? And how do I simplify them? @brhans

Comment: Or in other words, implement all the functions, then select one with a multiplexer driven by (A,B) inputs ...

Comment: I am sorry I did not understand well. @Antonio51

Comment: As your truth table shows, when A 0 B 1, then F == C and you ignore D.

Comment: How do I simplify them ? How can I create Karnaugh maps? @brhans

Comment: If you don't know what a multiplexer is, see this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplexer#:~:text=In%20electronics%2C%20a%20multiplexer%20(or,inputs%20known%20as%20select%20lines.

Comment: This exercise is a simple means to introduce later a general application which is an "Arithmetic and Logic Unit" or ALU used in all "computers". as @brhans stated, the simple circuit is a "big" logic realization with all variables A, B, C, D, case a-). With a multiplexer, it is case c-). Case b-) is another means to select the function (which is quasi "also" the case c-).

Comment: NB: C, D are not really "outputs". They are "inputs" and the function F=C means that it "can" became also an "output" ...

Comment: I think there are subjects in this question that I haven't learned yet. I will learn the alu design you mentioned in the coming weeks. I only learned decoder and bool algebra. @Antonio51

Comment: Ok. Go slowly but surely. Can you see this http://www.32x8.com/var3.html

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: You need to ask the instructor for help. We won't do your homework for you, and your questions show that you really need more than we can give you in this space.

Comment: In the link I provided, choose the "4 variables" choice. Then, fill the table for all cases of logical values of A, B, C, and D. Choose also the value accordingly of the output named Y (NB: only 0 or 1). X is for another kind of exercise. Choose SOP (Sum Of Products), Click also "highlight groups", then and click "submit".

Comment: Thank you for everything @Antonio51

Comment: These are exam preparation questions. I just wanted to get ideas here and I got ideas. Please don't judge people too soon. @kruemi

Comment: When your work ended, it would be nice to do your "own answer" ... for newbies ... Ok, it should be rather "long" for the 3 cases ... Thanks.

Comment: This is also useful https://www.electrically4u.com/what-is-a-decoder-operation-types-and-applications/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here an example (case b) you should understand, EE&O.
Made with free [microcap v12](http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/mc12cd.zip)

[image]

Comment: thank you so much.

Comment: Have used the link for case a-) ?

Comment: No ı havent used